# How do we create the pagination links in Spring?

Tags: spring, jsp, pagination

I could just do it statically without fetching the total number of pages there would be, but that's not how we do it usually.

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/posts?page=1">1</a>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/posts?page=2">2</a>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/posts?page=3">3</a>
```

So I was wondering what was the best way to create pagination links on our JSP. I only use JSP, Spring and Hibernate, so a method that doesn't require anything else would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create numbered page links, you typically need prior knowledge to the total number of whatever you're paging as well as a page's rendered size.  With these two pieces of data, you can easily construct links.

Libraries such as `DisplayTag` use the page size combined with a list of objects to draw the links using simple JSP tags.

All of this is irrespective of Spring and Hibernate.  Only if you want to optimize the data fetch by doing a COUNT query combined with a query to fetch only a specific page of data based on page size and page number would any care need to be made in Hibernate's court.

Comment: We can combine the two queries into one? I was thinking of doing two queries, but thought that would be bad performance wise, so I hesitated a lot before committing to anything.

Comment: @jarvan If you don't mind tying yourself to Hibernate's `ScrollableResults`, you can use that to advance to the first row of interest, get the next pageSize number of rows, and then advance the end of the results to get the number of rows queried if you must do it in one query.  If you must adhere to JPA specifications without using Hibernate proprietary options, then 2 queries is your only choice.   Depending on your data model, the 2 query approach can be faster.  Additionally, if you can submit parallel queries in your service tier, you can get both the count and data simultaneously.